# Upgrade 2.5 to 3.4 gives error 1050 and 1146

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Joomla 2.5 to 3.4 already for 4 days now, but no luck.

I have followed all these steps: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration

I have removed all components that might give an issue (such as JoomDoc, JoomGallery, JSN Power Admin)

I have tried all these steps:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=826530 and these steps: (I have no access to posting more then 2 links, so I can't show you)

I have tried to follow this: (I have no access to posting more then 2 links, so I can't show you)

But nothing, really nothing works. Every time I try something and then update again, or try something and go back to my site, I get these 2 errors:
First error 1050 and then error 1146: Table 'Reflex.nwo4j_postinstall_messages' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `nwo4j_postinstall_messages`

I really don't know what to do anymore.

We had Joomla 2-5-17, upgraded (as explained in the tutorial) first to 2-5-28, the requirements for the PHP version, MySQL version,... we have checked as well. Everything is good, but we just don't seem to be able to upgrade.

If anybody can help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to copy over `libraries` folder form the 3.4 installation. 
Then try to access `/index.php?option=com_installer&view=discover` and click on "Find". It should find all not installed components during update. Then check them and click "Install".

Also you can try to create `postinstall_messages` table manually in the DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nwo4j_postinstall_messages` (
`postinstall_message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`extension_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 700 COMMENT 'FK to #__extensions',
`title_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Lang key for the title',
`description_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Lang key for description',
`action_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`language_extension` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'com_postinstall' COMMENT 'Extension holding lang keys',
`language_client_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`type` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'link' COMMENT 'Message type - message, link, action',
`action_file` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'RAD URI to the PHP file containing action method',
`action` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Action method name or URL',
`condition_file` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'RAD URI to file holding display condition method',
`condition_method` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Display condition method, must return boolean',
`version_introduced` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3.2.0' COMMENT 'Version when this message was introduced',
`enabled` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
PRIMARY KEY (`postinstall_message_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `nwo4j_postinstall_messages` (`extension_id`, `title_key`, `description_key`, `action_key`, `language_extension`, `language_client_id`, `type`, `action_file`, `action`, `condition_file`, `condition_method`, `version_introduced`, `enabled`) VALUES
(700, 'PLG_TWOFACTORAUTH_TOTP_POSTINSTALL_TITLE', 'PLG_TWOFACTORAUTH_TOTP_POSTINSTALL_BODY', 'PLG_TWOFACTORAUTH_TOTP_POSTINSTALL_ACTION', 'plg_twofactorauth_totp', 1, 'action', 'site://plugins/twofactorauth/totp/postinstall/actions.php', 'twofactorauth_postinstall_action', 'site://plugins/twofactorauth/totp/postinstall/actions.php', 'twofactorauth_postinstall_condition', '3.2.0', 1),
(700, 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_EACCELERATOR_TITLE', 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_EACCELERATOR_BODY', 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_EACCELERATOR_BUTTON', 'com_cpanel', 1, 'action', 'admin://components/com_admin/postinstall/eaccelerator.php', 'admin_postinstall_eaccelerator_action', 'admin://components/com_admin/postinstall/eaccelerator.php', 'admin_postinstall_eaccelerator_condition', '3.2.0', 1),
(700, 'COM_CPANEL_WELCOME_BEGINNERS_TITLE', 'COM_CPANEL_WELCOME_BEGINNERS_MESSAGE', '', 'com_cpanel', 1, 'message', '', '', '', '', '3.2.0', 1),
(700, 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_PHPVERSION_TITLE', 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_PHPVERSION_BODY', '', 'com_cpanel', 1, 'message', '', '', 'admin://components/com_admin/postinstall/phpversion.php', 'admin_postinstall_phpversion_condition', '3.2.2', 1),
(700, 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_ROBOTS_TITLE', 'COM_CPANEL_MSG_ROBOTS_BODY', '', 'com_cpanel', 1, 'message', '', '', '', '', '3.4.0', 1);
```

Comment: My husband owns the databases and by installing the table manually, he saw that there was an issue with innodb. This seems to have solved the problem, so thank you very much for showing us the right direction. But now I have a problem with the frontend, giving an error on 500: jhtmlerror:: mootools not found. I will search this issue a bit further, but off course, if anyone has any ideas, you can let me know.

Comment: @Lien I am glad that was able to help. Please accept my answer to close this question! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing your database by going to:

**Joomla backend** >> **Extension Manager** >> **Database**

Or simply:

```
www.YOUR_SITE.COM/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=database
```

Then click the **fix** button if any errors occur

Comment: I have tried this already, this doesn't make any difference. I can't access my backend or frontend anymore. And when I follow the link you give me (which I found also on different other sites), it gets even worse and I get this error: Notice: Undefined property: InstallerController::$input in /home/data_1/Reflex/administrator/components/com_installer/controller.php on line 37

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/data_1/Reflex/administrator/components/com_installer/controller.php on line 37